# Security Validation Error

Tags: security, user-controls, runwithelevatedprivileges

I'm trying to create a spweb in page_load via a control on the site. I get the error "The security validation for this page is invalid".

I've got a postback (No GET-Request) and also tried SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest in the onInit-Method and directly before RunWithElevatedPrivileagues.

I've placed a FormDigest Control on the ascx of my control. The masterpage is Seattle.master and contains the formdigestplceholder and control.

It works on the dev-system with farm-account but not on the integrationsystem. I'm on SP2013.

Any suggestions?

**[Update 2]** Ok the code in Update 1 wasn't the real problem. The real problem occured in the following line:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "CreateMeetingRepost", "document.forms[0].submit();", true);
```

In the Page_Load I'm registering this code to submit the site to itself for getting a postback. But after the postback occures and control is fully loaded the page is getting a security validation error somewhere else (not in my code). Any suggestions?

All I want to do is create a subsite. I tried AllowUnsafeUpdate on Rootweb and Site but that didn't work. SharePoint throws an innerexception while copying contenttype to the new web.

**[Update1 - Not the Problem]** Some Code - MeetingManager.CreateMeetingAndFillUrl creates the subsite

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
            {
                using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
                {
                    using (SPLongOperation operation = new SPLongOperation(this.Page))
                    {
                        operation.LeadingHTML = "Meeting wird erstellt";
                        operation.Begin();
                        MeetingManager.CreateMeetingAndFillUrl(elevatedSite, currentMeeting);

                        try
                        {
                            operation.End(currentMeeting.Url);
                        }
                        catch (ThreadAbortException)
                        {
                            // This exception is thrown because the SPLongOperation.End
                            // calls a Response.End internally
                            // see: http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/2011/08/sharepoint-how-to-use-splongoperation/
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: 1) Don't have a web for site creation 2) I thought it's better to use validateformdigest

Comment: Can you share the code pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. All the code is correct but there is an error in March 2013 PU. The FormDigest is set invalid and when doing a post the error occures. This is a real bad error.

http://nikpatel.net/2013/09/06/sharepoint-march-2013-public-update-invalid-formdigest-client-svc-processquery-403-forbidden/